# Is dynamic creation of entities supported in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

Imagine I need to create "x" tables whose names are present in a configuration file.

Does spring provides any way to read the table names from this configuration file on boot and create corresponding entity classes at run time which are then mapped to different tables in the same database & same schema?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: It would not make much sense to automatically generate entity classes at runtime. You'd have to write code to use those classes - or would you also want your program to generate the code that uses those classes? You'd be writing a program that writes a program at runtime... Can you explain why you would want to do this? Maybe there's a better way to solve your *actual* problem.

Comment: Downvoted because http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Thanks @Jesper for your comment. The answer to your question is because the tables to be created are not known at the compile time. When the application is deployed, user decides which tables they want & based on this our application should be capable of creating entities (and thus tables) at run time. What I understand after reading through different posts - the only way out is to have the different entities (corresponding to a different table) created before executing the spring boot application.

Comment: Upvoted because some people have too much anger :D